# How do I flush the Javascript/CSS Cache using a SSH command line in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

how do I flush or delete the Javascript/CSS Cache using a SSH command line in Magento 1.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 => Go to your Project Root Directory Location and Run Below Mention CMD.

```
$rm -rf var/cache/*
$rm -rf var/session/*
```

Comment: Thanks for that.